# Retain visited link color after right click and page refresh

Tags: jquery, css, anchor

Using the following, I am allowing the user to right click on a link to open in a new tab/window. I want the link to change color to purple to show it has been visited. The problem is that I can't get the link color to retain the purple property when the user refreshes the page. Also having an issue keeping the links such as "a.advanced" from changing color.

```
//Sets anchor link color to purple when right clicked and opened as new tab/window. 
$(document).on("mousedown", "a",

function (e) {
    if (e.button == 2) {
        $(this).css("color", "purple");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

//sets color of visited anchor links to purple.

$('a:visited').css("color", "#416b99");

//Keeps navigation items white when user right clicks to open in a new tab/window.
$(document).on("mousedown", "a.nav-item, a.advanced, a.user-support, a.user-myknovel, a.user-welcome",

function (e) {
    if (e.button == 2) {
        $(this).css("color", "white");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser by default changes the color of the link to purple when you click on the link.
It will be shown in purple color till you clear your cache.

I guess your problem is

You apply the css inside some function. So when you refresh the page, the style will not be applied unless you call that function.

Try moving the

a:visited { color: #416b99; }

part to a css file.

If it doesn't work put up your markup and css and scripts

```
a:visited {
            color: green;
        }

<a href="#">Link</a>
```

This works perfectly. Whether you right click or not the browser detects the visited links until you clear your cache.

Comment: The issue is that it isn't by default when you are RIGHT clicking.

Comment: oops din't see the word right click. Ok we will make it happen :)

Comment: dud, the class is applied only when the user right clicks on the link right?? Then what do you expect when the page is reloaded. ??

Comment: I had it at one point, but the issue is that when you set it for all anchor links, the few navigation links I have set to retain their white color value are overridden by the function for general anchor links.

Comment: The same should happen when the user right clicks as when they left click. If a user opens the link in a new tab, clicks the breadcrumb to go back one page to the original page they were at in the new tab, the color is not retained. Does that make sense?

Comment: You cannot do that like this. Just think. you apply the rule inside the right click handler. By default when the page is loaded the color is unvisited. The rule gets applied only when the user again rightclicks the link. You cannot make it happen with this logic

Comment: Let me check it again. Try moving a:visited into a css file

Comment: It is perfectly working for me when i right clicked. move the rules to css. Use jquery only when needed when styling elements.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38734/discussion-between-arun-aravind-and-matt)